# Cassandra data modelling less then 1000 records to fit in one row

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, key-value-store

We have some entity uniquely identified by generated UUID. We need to support find by name query. Also we need to support sorting to be by name.

We know that there will be no more than 1000 of entities of that type which can perfectly fit in one row. Is it viable idea to hardcode primary key, use name as clustering key and id as clustering key there to satisfy uniqueness. Lets say we need school entity. Here is example:

```
CREATE TABLE school (
  constant text,
  name text,
  id uuid,
  description text,
  location text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((constant), name, id)
);
```

Initial state would be give me all schools and then filtering by exact name will happen. Our reasoning behind this was to place all schools in single row for fast access, have name as clustering column for filtering and have id as clustering column to guaranty uniqueness. We can use `constant = school` as known hardcoded value to access this row.

What I like about this solution is that all values are in one row and we get fast reads. Also we can solve sorting easy by clustering column. What I do not like is hardcoded value for `constant` which seams odd. We could use `name` as PK but then we would have 1000 records spread across couple of partitions, probably find all without name would be slower and would not be sorted.

**Question 1**

Is this viable solution and are there any problems with it which we do not see? I did not see any example on Cassandra data modelling with hardcoded primary key probably for the reason so we are doubting this solution.

**Question 2**

Name is editable field, it will probably be changed rarely (someone can make typo or school can change name) but it can change. What is best way to achieve this? Delete insert inside batch (LTE can be applied to same row with conditional clause)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is a good approach for such a small dataset.  Just because Cassandra can partition large datasets across multiple nodes does not mean that you need to use that ability for every table.  By using a constant for the partition key, you are telling Cassandra that you want the data to be stored on one node where you can access it quickly and in sorted order.  Relational databases act on data in a single node all the time, so this is really not such an unusual thing to do.

For safety you will probably want to use a replication factor higher than one so that there are at least two copies of the single partition.  In that way you will not lose access to the data if the one node where it is stored went down.

This approach could cause problems if you expect to have a lot of clients (i.e. thousands of clients) frequently reading and writing to this table, since it could become a hot spot.  With only 1000 records you can probably keep all the rows cached in memory by setting the table to cache all keys and rows.

You probably won't find a lot of examples where this is done because people move to Cassandra for the support of large datasets where they want the scalability that comes from using multiple partitions.  So examples are geared towards that.

Comment: Thanks for thorough answer and note on many clients, did not think of that. I have one additional question for this, name of school is editable, what is best strategy for that? It will be changed rarely but someone can make typo, do delete insert?

Comment: I added this part to question in question 2 also. Your answer covers everything so I will accept, this is like a bonus if you have opinion on that, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, to modify a name you'll need to do a delete of the old name and insert with the new name since it is not permitted to update a key column.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this viable solution and are there any problems with it which we do not see? I did not see any example on Cassandra data modelling with hardcoded primary key probably for the reason so we are doubting this solution.

I briefly addressed this type of modeling solution earlier this year in my article: [We Shall Have Order!](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/we-shall-have-order/)  This is what is known as a "dummy key," where each row has the same partition key.  This is a shortcut that allows you to easily order all of your rows (on an unbound `SELECT *`) by clustering column(s).

Problems with this solution:

- Cassandra allows a maximum of 2 billion column values per partition key.  When using a dummy partition key, you will approach this limit with each value that you add.
- Your data will all be stored in the same partition, which will create a "hot spot" (large groupings of data) in your cluster.  This means that your data model will immediately void one of Cassandra's main benefits...data distribution.  This will also complicate load balancing (the same nodes and ranges will keep serving all of your requests).
- I can see that your model is designed around a `SELECT *` query.  Cassandra works best when you can give it specific keys to query by.  Unbound `SELECT *` queries (queries without WHERE clauses) are not a good idea to be doing with Cassandra, as they can lead to timeouts (as your data grows).

From reading through your question, I know that you're going to say that you're only using it for 1000 rows.  That your dataset won't ever grow much beyond those 1000 rows, so you won't hit any of the roadblocks that I have mentioned.

So then I have to wonder, *why are you using Cassandra?*  As a Cassandra MVP, that's a question I don't ask often.  But you don't have an especially large data set (which is what Cassandra is designed to work with).  Relying on that fact as a reason to use a product *incorrectly* is not really the best solution.

Honestly, I am going to recommend that you save yourself some complexity, and use a RDBMS instead.  That will fit your use case significantly better than Cassandra will.  Then you can update and order by whatever fields you wish.

Comment: Thanks for answer. This is just one table in dataset. We are using it for analytics, and voting platform which has couple of thousand votes a day. So we have viable use case. We are aware that some of our data better belong to RDBMS, but we decided that cost of maintenance and integration for two storage sources is larger than using cassandra for some tables not by the book. Going with 2 or even 3 storage solutions is probably proper asnwer but this is MVP product (speed is essential)

Comment: Also `SELECT *` star is admin panel usage, which will be used rarely, on frontend part we will have `users_by_school` and `schools_by_user` which will go in separate tables. Finding school by name is only admin aid to go faster to desired school and make changes. Think most proper modeling is `school_by_id` and do application level name filtering.

Comment: Just finished datastax modeling course https://academy.datastax.com/courses/ds220-data-modeling, in 3rd chapter from end (Use Cases: Sensor Data) there is example like mine and Jamie King suggests to use bucket (artifical column as key) for data which will have small amount of values to have single query hit single partion. That will create hotspots but it is in official learning material for cassandra certification. Is that than good idea or not?